# Getting friendly name of serial port from Windows Message in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, serial-port

I am having a problem acquiring the friendly name (dbcp_name) from DEV_BROADCAST_PORT using delphi.

I have tried using the microsoft help documentation which says it is a pointer to a null terminated string, but on that page there is a comment which indicates it is a variable-length structure, and dbcp_name is an array that contains the actual characters of the port name.

I have tried to extract this but I currently have not found a way as when I get it to return anything it is complete gibberish.

The code I have used follows:

```
PDevBroadcastPort = ^DEV_BROADCAST_PORT;

DEV_BROADCAST_PORT = packed record
    dbcp_size : DWORD ;
    dbcp_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbcp_reserved : DWORD ;
    dbcp_name : array[0..0] of ansichar; //TCHAR dbcp_name[1]; not valid
end;
```

I have tried different values for the length of the array, I had read somewhere that this was the correct declaration but I am not entirely sure. Also the commented out line is what the microsoft document gives for the line in C++

To extract the information I have tried this:

```
var
  PData: PDevBroadcastPort;

  FName: string;

  ...

  PData := PDevBroadcastPort(Msg.lParam);

  ShowMessage('Length '+Inttostr(length(PData^.dbcp_name)));

  FName := '';

  i:=0;

  while((PData^.dbcp_name[i]) <> #0) and (i < 100) do
      begin
          FName := FName + (PData.dbcp_name[i]);

          i := i +1;

          ShowMessage(FName); 
      end;
```

I have tried setting the while loop to terminate at the length of the data structure but if I dont set it then it becomes huge.

Any help is appreciated and if I have left out any code which is needed for this question please let me know and I shall acquire it as soon as I can.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to start with a memory dump to see what is there.

Comment: The CPU view in the debugger can show you whatever memory you want. Give it the address stored in `PData` and see whether it matches what the documentation says to expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say it's a *pointer* to a null-terminated string; it says it *is* a null-terminated string. That's typical for arrays that are declared at the end of a record with a length of just one element.

There's actually more memory after the designated record size, and that memory holds the remaining characters of the string. A pointer to that record field is also a pointer to the character data.

```
FName := PAnsiChar(@PData.dbcp_name);
```

Your array-traversing code should work, too, assuming you have bounds checking disabled for that stretch of code (or else you'd get an exception when the program detected you reading beyond the first element of the array).

That all presupposes that `PData` really is a pointer to a `Dev_Broadcast_Port` structure. You've given no information about what message you're handing, so I don't know whether you really have what you think you have.

If you're using Delphi 2009 or later, then the `TCHAR` type in the C declaration is equivalent to Delphi's `WideChar` type. Interpreting the field as an array of `AnsiChar` will get you wrong results, although for most port names, it might appear as though the array is a list of null-terminated one-character strings. Unless you're sure you have non-Unicode data, you should just use `Char` and `PChar`, and let the Delphi version determine which data type you have.

```
FName := PChar(@PData.dbcp_name);
```

Comment: I didn't have to do anything with bounds checking but I changed:

    FName := FName + (PData.dbcp_name[i]);

to

    FName := FName + PAnsiChar(@PData.dbcp_name[i]);

Thanks

Comment: Huh? If you still have the loop, then you're appending several *strings*, not just single *characters*. And if you don't have the loop, then you don't need the `i` variable at all. I'm beginning to wonder whether you're using Delphi 209 or later, and the characters you have are really WideChar instead of AnsiChar. The code you've described should not work.

Comment: I also changed the record to dbcp_name : array[0..10] of ansichar; and it is working now. I'm using Delphi XE 2.

Comment: If you're using Delphi XE2, then are you sure the record really contains `AnsiChar`? The C declaration used `TCHAR`, which means it will hold `wchar_t` when compiled in Unicode mode. Delphi XE2 is in Unicode, so `TCHAR` should be equivalent to `WideChar`. Casting to `PAnsiChar` is wrong.

Comment: Using WideChar sort of works but it gives a string that doesn't seem to terminate properly. Ansichar gives Com3 then stops. I'm sure you're right, maybe there is something in my code that means ansichar works

Answer (score 0):

The `dbcp_name` field contains the actual characters.  The length of the character data, minus the null terminator, is `dbcp_size - SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_PORT)`, so you can grab the name like this:

```
type
  DEV_BROADCAST_PORTA = packed record
    dbcp_size : DWORD;
    dbcp_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbcp_reserved : DWORD;
    dbcp_name : array[0..0] of AnsiChar;
  end; 

  DEV_BROADCAST_PORTW = packed record
    dbcp_size : DWORD;
    dbcp_devicetype : DWORD;
    dbcp_reserved : DWORD;
    dbcp_name : array[0..0] of WideChar;
  end; 

  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  DEV_BROADCAST_PORT = DEV_BROADCAST_PORTW;
  {$ELSE}
  DEV_BROADCAST_PORT = DEV_BROADCAST_PORTA;
  {$ENDIF}
  PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT = ^DEV_BROADCAST_PORT;
```

.

```
var
  PData: PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT;
  FName: string;

...
PData := PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT(Msg.lParam);
SetString(FName, PData^.dbcp_name, (PData^.dbcp_size - SizeOf(DEV_BROADCAST_PORT)) div SizeOf(Char));
ShowMessage(FName);
```